# Can someone provide a link to verses and their respective English translation of Brihad-Jabala & Bhasma-jabala Upanishad

Tags: shiva, upanishads, resource

Can someone provide link to verse to verse translations of [Brihad Jabala Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brihajjabala_Upanishad) and 
[Bhasma Jabala Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhasmajabala_Upanishad)

There should be verse in Sanskrit with corresponding translation in English.

Answer (score 1):

**Brihad-Jabala**

Sanskrit - [here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/brihajjabala.pdf)

English - [here](http://www.celextel.org/upanishads/atharva_veda/brihadjabala.html)

**Bhasma-jabala Upanishad**

Sanskrit - [here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/bhasma.html?lang=sa)

English - [here](http://www.celextel.org/upanishads/atharva_veda/bhasma-jabala.html)

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I have see this link already. I wanted translation and verse side by side, unfortunately I can't discern which translation is pointing to which verse

Comment: "here" is not a very good way of redirecting people to other links. You should mention where the link will take us.Add website name when you add link. Another thing is the site you are giving has copy righted material of the site. It is not good to share them. Please add another link.